# Dimmer with zero-crossing circuit and TRIAC

Tags: triac, dimmer

I want to make a dimmer to control a huge power resistance of 700W. For this, I made a circuit that detected when the wave reaches zero (the circuit above the figure) and another that controls the TRIAC that controls the current that goes to charge.

[image: Circuit]

The zero detection circuit is working fine, but the control circuit does not. I'm controlling everything for Raspberry. The code is only a function that is triggered by the interruption of zero detection. This function waits a certain time (depending on how much I want the wave to pass) and then a pin (which is what goes to the optocoupler and then to TRIAC). However, regardless of the time I put to wait, the output is always the same as the AC input, ie always 220V. Do you have any idea what might be happening?

I've already checked that Raspberry is sending the signal correctly and it is. So I think the problem is on the TRIAC or optocoupler side.

I'm using this components:
R2,R8=180R ¼ w, 180R 1w
R6,R4=680R ¼ w, 680R 1w
R5=39R 3w
R5=56K 1w
R7=10K ¼ w
R1=1M ¼ w
C4=100nF
C3=100nF 230V ~
C1=10nF 630V~
U1=MOC3021
U2=4N35
U4=BT136
Q1=BC547B

Thank you!!

Comment: Please repost the schematic with the grid turned off. It is not legible. Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: Apart from the schematic being less than legible, I see two independent snubbering / avalanche-limitation schemes in parallel, thus my question: Are you actually measuring the output with a load? Any load at all?

Comment: Im sorry, i changed the image. Now you guys can see it?

Comment: Im so sorry, but i dont know what snubbering is. But anyway, when i measured the output i was using oscilloscope and this resistance load. The tests were made on the physical circuit.

Comment: Do you have the load attached? Without a low-resistance load attached you will read almost mains voltage due to the snubber and triac leakage.

Comment: Yes, Spehro. When i tested, it was with the load attached. 
And despite sending different times for triac activation, the load (which is a 700W resistor) continued to heat up, as if the triac did not influence.

Comment: Okay, divide and conquer- remove the drive signal, then if the triac stays on, remove U1 and test again.

Comment: Did you monitor the opto-LED terminals with the oscilloscope to check that the control circuit is working as expected?

Comment: But Spehro, if I remove the optocoupler, is there no danger of burning my Raspberry?

Comment: Yes, Transistor, at the input terminals there were 1.1V and the output 220V. I also tested the optocoupler inputs to check if the Raspberry was correctly sending the pulses, and it was. ):

Comment: By "remove" I mean unplug it, leaving all the previous connections open, **not** bypass it.

Answer (score 2):

Replace R2(in your schematic) with a lower value, 120R worked fine during simulation. If still not working, make sure ZC interrupt occurs every 10ms.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: At 5v 120R was enough, at 3.3v a 100R should work. Pulse duration should be ~100uS.